# Assigning prototype inside constructor

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
var MyClass = function(b) {
    this.a = b;
    this.getA = function() {
        return that.a;
    }
}

var SecondClass = function(b) {
    this.prototype = new MyClass(b);
    this.getB = function() {
        return 6;
    }
}

var a = new SecondClass(2);
console.log(a.getA());
```

The output tells me that a has no method called getA()

I assumed that doing this.prototype = new MyClass() inside the constructor for SecondClass would cause it to inhert methods from MyClass?

I'm sure there are better ways to do this, but I am trying to understand the behaviour of the prototype keyword.

Comment: "prototype" is not a keyword.

Comment: `return that.a;` should be `return this.a;` btw.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`prototype` is a special property of the **constructor function**, not of the **instance**.

When you call the constructor function with `new Func()`, the engine will create a new object which inherits from `Func.prototype` and then sets `this` inside the constructor function to refer to the new object.

So, aside from `this.prototype` just being an ordinary property, the inheritance already took place when the assignment takes place.

Since you are not assigning any methods to `MyClass.prototype`, you don't have to do anything with prototype inheritance here. All you have to do is apply `MyClass` to the newly created instance using [`.call` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call):

```
var SecondClass = function(b) {
    MyClass.call(this, b);
    this.getB = function() {
        return 6;
    }
};
```

---

However, you should [add all methods that are shared by instances to the prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/q/310870/218196) and then let each instance of `SecondClass` inherit from it. This is how a complete setup could look like:

```
var MyClass = function(b) {
    this.a = b;
}
MyClass.prototype.getA = function() {
    return this.a;
};

var SecondClass = function(b) {
    // call parent constructor (like 'super()' in other languages)
    MyClass.call(this, b);
}
// Setup inheritance - add 'MyClass.prototype' to the prototype chain
SecondClass.prototype = Object.create(MyClass.prototype);
SecondClass.prototype.getB = function() {
    return 6;
};

var a = new SecondClass(2);
console.log(a.getA());
```

---

All of this [will become easier in ES6](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=strawman:maximally_minimal_classes).

Comment: Thanks, this helped make things a bit clearer. Just to clarify, I assume that MyClass.protoype will just be an instance of Object. So when I assign stuff to MyClass.prototype it only assigns them to a specific instance of object (that is prototype for MyClass), not the Object "class" itself. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

A property called "prototype" is only interesting on objects that are functions. Assigning a value to the "prototype" property in your constructor has no effect (in this case); what matters would be the "prototype" property of the constructor function itself.

```
SecondClass.prototype = new MyClass();
```

or something. The prototype object of a constructor is shared among all the instances constructed, so having the prototype vary by a constructor parameter also doesn't make a lot of sense.

Another thing you could do would be to call the "MyClass" constructor from inside "SecondClass":

```
function SecondClass(b) {
  MyClass.call(this, b);
  this.getB = function() {
    return 6;
  };
}
```

That would have the effect of making the `this` that's constructed in the `new SecondClass()` call be decorated by the "MyClass" constructor. It wouldn't really be inheritance, but you'd get a "getA" function.