# scope of this for constructor function

Tags: javascript

Can someone help me clarify the difference between thetwo ways of creating constructor function in javascript?
Here is the code:

```
var globarcheck= this;
var Car = function(color){
    this.color= color;
    /*this.prototype.Go = function()
    {
        console.log(this.color+" "+"Car going...");
    };*/
};

Car.prototype.Go= function(){
    console.log(this.color+" "+"Car going...");
};
var aCar = new Car("green");
var bCar = new Car("yellow");
aCar.Go();
bCar.Go();
```

The above code works but why I can't use the commented out code to do the same to assign the Go method?

Comment: `prototype` is a property of the **constructor function** (i.e. `Car`) *not* of the **instance** (i.e. `this`). `this.prototype` does not exist and does not have a special meaning.

Comment: related: [Assigning prototype inside constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16173901/218196).

Answer (score 6):

In the commented out code you're trying to associate a method with an instance, and not the type itself. 
The prototype is meant to create members at the type level (Car), and not for specific instances

Answer (score 0):

When you do `new Car()` then `this` is the new object instanceof Car, not the function Car.

Because of that, you do add a prototype shared function, before you create a new object (instance)of the constructor function.

What you could do is to set an instance function (not prototype shared) in the constructor:

```
var Car = function (color, useGoInInstance) {
    this.color = color;

    if (useGoInInstance) {
        this.Go = function ()
        {
            console.log(this.color+" "+"Car going (instance override)...");
        };
    }
};

Car.prototype.Go = function () {
    console.log(this.color+" "+"Car going (shared)...");
};
var aCar = new Car("green");
var bCar = new Car("yellow", true);
aCar.Go(); // uses shared function
bCar.Go(); // uses instance function
```